# How to import libraries in PHP

Tags: php

I am normally an ASP.NET developer who wants to migrate to PHP. I am taking quite a time to learn it and I am wondering how to use libraries in PHP?

Do I need to use `require` or `include` to import a library into my project to use the `classes`, `functions` etc. defined in the library? Or something else.

I running PHP on the Apache web server what I've found is for Zend Server and it looked weird to me.

Can someone explain me overall steps to import and start using libraries in my own code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use both.

Require will throw a fatal error if the file is not found.

```
require('lib.class.php');
```

You could use include if you need to continue the script even if the file couldn't get loaded.

Like:

```
 if (!include('lib')) {
   doWhatever();
 }
```

Comment: @Braveyard: Also see [`__autoload`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), [`spl_autoload`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php), `require_once` and `include_once`. @yes123 and OP: Note that require and include are not functions, so the parentheses is not needed.

Comment: @Braveyard: don't see *_once because they are performance killer. (cit by Lerdorf creator of php http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/38-The-no-framework-PHP-MVC-framework.html )

Comment: @yes123: Won't you get an error for attempting to redeclare a class without `*_once` if you aren't careful, or am I mistaken? Also, from your link: `the *_once() calls are very slow under an opcode cache. Sometimes there is no way around using these calls`

Comment: Yes of course you should never include a file 2 times if it got some declaration

Comment: @Brave: you can write both `require('lib');` or `require 'lib';` If you don't want to use parthenesis (dunno why) in the if you need to do a `if ( (include 'lib') === false ) {}`

Comment: Using extra parentheses does "work", but you must understand that those are not functions, and don't accept arguments, it's like `echo`. You can use any amount of parentheses in PHP like `echo (((("Hello"))));` and it will not cause an error, but it's better to not use them when you don't have to.

Comment: require and echo are language constructs that's why they can be used without parentheses. But yeah it looks much clear w/o parentheses to me.